# При повторном открытии фрагмента не работает ViewPager и содержимое фрагмента пусто

Tags: java, android

Доброе время суток. Подскажите пожалуйста, как разрешить мою проблему. Запускаю фрагмент - все отлично (он содержит RecyclerView, а под AppBar находится ViewPager). Содержимое страницы (Recycler) присутствует. Но когда я открываю другой фрагмент, а затем возвращаюсь к прежнему, ViewPager перестает работать (он не переключает страницы, а ползунок приходится вручную тягать от края до края), а также сама страница оказывается пустой.

Как думаете, в чем может быть проблема и что следует предоставить?

Comment: Покажите код фрагмента. У вас проблема с восстановлением состояния - при нём вы не производите повторную инициализацию нужного. Скорее всего поможет перенос кода инициализации ViewPager и прочего в другой  метод жизненного цикла.

Comment: Прикрепил код фрагмента.

Comment: Попробуйте перенести `createRecyclerItems(view.getContext(), recyclerView); // заполняет поле RecyclerItems
    loadMessages();` в onResume

Comment: К сожалению, ничего не изменилось...

Comment: Ещё  у вас пропущено super.onViewCreated. И не видно вообще ViewPager в коде предоставленном

Comment: У меня есть NavigationDrawer. Внутри него, соответственно, множество вкладок, каждая из которых - отдельный фрагмент. При нажатии в этой менюшке на "Общение" открывается фрагмент с ViewPager. И именно этот ViewPager перестает работать. Одна вкладка ViewPager'a отвечает за сообщение (и ее класс представлен мною). Вторая - за список пользователей. Прикрепил код, в котором есть ViewPager.

Comment: Ну, собственно вам надо, по идее, перенести весь код с ViewPager из onCreateView в onViewCreated или в onResume

Comment: Проверил оба варианта. К сожалению, тоже не помогло. Все равно этот ViewPager "ломается", а текст перестает отображаться (содержимое RecyclerView).

Comment: Вы точно весь код перенесли в onResume? Это должно было сработать. Если весь и не работает - других идей нет( С IDE я бы разобрался, но времени на это совсем нет(

Comment: Я добавил в шапку темы обновленный ChatFragment (с перенесенным ViewPager). Но я думаю сделал все правильно. Аналогично поступал с onResume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема разрешена. Заменил getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() на getChildFragmentManager().